# Using AMP only single post wordpress

Tags: wordpress, accelerated-mobile-page

I want include AMP to my website - Using online single post - How can I direct from none-amp to amp via code

That means single post link to amp pages of single post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for the same https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/.

They have alot of customization options. They even have an option to redirect for mobile pages. Give it a try, it will save you alot of time and make your job much easier without having to pay for it :)

Comment: Yeah this is very useful plugin. Recommended for amp implementations

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.